# CONCAT two cells if VLOOKUP result is the right value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm looking for some help on a budgeting spreadsheet. Recently I've been asked to put together a workbook with various tabs for my work that will be used for budgeting. On in workbook I have a tab for the 'Tech - Expenses' and another tab for 'Server Costs'

The 'Server Cost' tab is suppose to outline all the potential options that we might be switching to. The 'Tech - Expenses' tab is the actual expenses that will feed in to the top sheet. Only one of the lines from 'Server Cost' can feed in to the 'Tech - Expenses'. What I would like to do is save the tediousness of having to copy & paste the server cost line the management team likes and want to use in to the 'Tech - Expenses' by creating a Boolean switch that if True would automatically feel the true line in to the 'Tech - Expenses' tab. I was wondering if there is a to do this, or a better automated way of feeding the information form the 'Server Cost' tab and in to the 'Tech - Expenses' tab.

What I would like to do is essentially something like the train of thought below:

If one of the cells in Column W = "Y" in 'Server Cost' than Concat Column A & B in 'Server Cost' and print out the concatenation in the cell in 'Tech - Expenses

Thanks for any help on this. Worst case it looks like will just need to switch between tabs and copy and paste. Just trying to go a bit of the "extra mile" on this one.

Comment: Use if(), logical test for “y” then do task.

Comment: Can you mock up some data to illustrate the problem plz? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP("Y",'Server Cost'!W:W,1,FALSE)="Y",CONCATENATE('Server Cost'!A1," + ",'Server Cost'!B1),"Did Not Find Y")
```

[image]